# Adding Collision to a object in citrus engine

Tags: actionscript-3, citrus-engine

I have a hero and a enemy,Now When a hero contact the enemy the hero should automatically fall down.How can I add a Collision method to it.

Comment: Please be way more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Well do some research! There are a lot of samples out there that Aymeric has posted.

The most common is to use the [SimpleCitrusSolver](https://github.com/alamboley/Citrus-Engine/blob/master/src/citrus/physics/simple/SimpleCitrusSolver.as). It's quite easy and is done with one line of code: `simpleCitrusSolver.collide(DynamicObject, StaticObject);`
You can find more for this in the [simple collision example](https://github.com/alamboley/Citrus-Engine-Examples/blob/master/src/simplecollision/SimpleGameState.as).

Other samples can be found at the [Citrus Engine Examples](https://github.com/alamboley/Citrus-Engine-Examples/tree/master/src) github page.